# T-SQL how to convert hour (int value) in hh:mm format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert the variables HOUR (INT), in time in this format hh:mm.
So I have this code;

```
declare @HOUR_NEW AS INT = 12
DECLARE @RISULTATO AS NVARCHAR(12)
SET @RISULTATO = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@HOUR_NEW,108)
SELECT @RISULTATO
```

I want the output is like this 12:00 but the select return 12

Comment: SQL Server has a `time` type. It would be better to use this instead of `int` or `varchar`

Comment: @bircastri Have you find your way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code include minutes and seconds with hours

```
declare @HOUR AS INT = 1, @MIN AS INT = 1, @SEC AS INT = 2
DECLARE @RISULTATO AS time(3)
SET @RISULTATO = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@HOUR) + ':' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@MIN) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @SEC) 
SELECT @RISULTATO
```

The above code is using data type time. If you just want to do it in your way you can use RIGHT e.g.

```
declare @HOUR_NEW AS INT = 1
DECLARE @RISULTATO AS time(1)
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @HOUR_NEW) ,2) + ':00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @HOUR_NEW AS INT = 12 
DECLARE @RISULTATO AS VARCHAR(12) 
SET @RISULTATO = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@HOUR_NEW) + ':00' SELECT @RISULTATO
```

Comment: but with your code if I have @HOUR_NEW = 1 the result is 1:00 and not 01:00

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
DECLARE @HOUR_NEW AS INT = 12
DECLARE @TIME TIME = '00:00:00';

SET @TIME = DATEADD(HOUR, @HOUR_NEW, @TIME);

PRINT LEFT(@TIME, 5);
```

I just declare `00:00:00` as current time and use `DATEADD()` to add amount of `@HOUR_NEW` hours to it. Then just print first 5 characters of it.

Answer (score 0):

below solution should work for you:

```
declare @result varchar(5) 
declare @hour int = 3
declare @hourString nvarchar(2) = (select cast(@hour as nvarchar))  

if (len(@hourString)<2)
    set @result =  '0' + @hourString + ':00' 
else
    set @result = @hourString + ':00' 

select @result
```